# Audio loops sometimes

Tags: sound

I installed more than 30 Linux distros on my machine but every one has a problem with sound. Sometimes it loops for a second or a half a second. I've searched on lots of forums but I can't find a solution!

Laptop: Toshiba Satellite c850-1g3

Comment: Does this issue occur on other OS's like Windows or BSD?